# PhpStorm: database host not accessible when in docker

Tags: postgresql, docker, phpstorm, datagrip, laravel-sail

Create simple Laravel application and up Laravel Sail.

Here is how database service looks in Docker Desktop:

[image]

Then try (unfortunately) to access this database host from PhpStorm Database Tools:

[image]

At this screenshot appear still unknown error of connection. More information you can see at the next screenshot when I try to open table (table list remains since this database connection was not in docker):

[image]

So, host `pgsql` is not reachable. Same for `localhost` or `host.docker.internal`.

How to open this database in PhpStorm Database Tools?

Comment: Please check the full error message in idea log found in Help - Show Log in Files or you can attach the log file via our tracker:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=DBE

Comment: Done. Waiting for an answer from JetBrains support service via YouTrack ticket